# Best way to create a react component for an array of data displayed in a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have an array of 4 objects, and I currently display them like this in my view:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <% @objects.each do |object| %>
      <td><%= object.property %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  ....
</table>
```

So each row is outputting the same value for each object in the array in columns.

Is there a way to create a React component that would output HTML/values for multiple objects in this way? So far from what I see in the documentation, components represent one instance of a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your `Table` component, and have separate render methods to iterate over your data and render the results.

```
_renderRow: function (obj, i) {
  return DOM.tr(null,
      DOM.td(null, obj.property)
  );
},

_renderTable: function () {
  var that = this;
  return objects.map( function (obj, i) {
      return that._renderRow(obj, i)
  })
},

render: function () {
  return DOM.table(null,
    this._renderTable()
  )
}
```

Full working table example: http://requirebin.com/?gist=279c45c30de8e4492874